# How to create Registry Entries in WiX 3.11 Installer for VSTO Add-ins deployment

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer, vsto

I'm trying to create a Windows Installer for deploying a [MS Office VSTO Add-In](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268878.aspx). As we may know, one of the requirements for installing a VSTO AddIn is to [create Registry Entries for VSTO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx). **Question**: How we can create such Registry Entries for VSTO in **WiX 3.11**?

Answer (score 0):

You create registry values in WiX following the pattern:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
    <Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
        <RegistryKey Root="HKCU"
                     Key="Software\Microsoft\MyApplicationName"
              Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
            <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="SomeIntegerValue" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
            <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="Default Value"/>
        </RegistryKey>
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

See [WiX documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/write_a_registry_entry.html)

Comment: There is a lot more to it then that.  For starters replicating that to each user who logs in.  Microsoft Office has a way to do this by registering in HKLM.  There is also a matter of chaining / gate checking all of the various prerequisite dependencies.   This is typically a 40 hour project for me and not easily answerable without posting a full solution as open source.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter The answer on SO is not supposed to provide a full-fledged product code.  According to the question, I gave the direction.  Next time I start new project I'll ask you to provide me with full solution.

Comment: Well, for any one reading this, make sure you search for how to leverage an  msi repair using ActiveSetup.  Otherwise the above solution will work for the person who installed the application but it won't work for anyone else.  Many developers wouldn't even know to test for this so it would likely make it to production before you even got your first complaint.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter ActiveSetup not needed anymore, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto/2010/03/08/deploying-your-vsto-add-ins-to-all-users-saurabh-bhatia/

Comment: @dvom, you might want to search my blog for the several VSTO articles that I posted 7-10 years ago.  I'm well aware of the multiple ways to deploy VSTO addins.  Your answer referenced HKCU not HKLM so in that scenario ActitveSetup would very much be needed.